# GCP Compute API creates VPC in legacy mode

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am using the below Go program to create a VPC in my Google Cloud Platform project.

```
func CreateGCPClient(ctx context.Context) (*compute.Service, error) {
    cred := option.WithCredentialsFile(path)
    return compute.NewService(ctx, cred)
}

func CreateNetworksService(s *compute.Service) *compute.NetworksService {
    return compute.NewNetworksService(s)
}

func CreateVPC(ctx context.Context, ns *compute.NetworksService, name string) (*compute.Operation, error) {
    net := &compute.Network{
        Name:                  name,
        AutoCreateSubnetworks: false,
        IPv4Range:             "",
    }
    return ns.Insert(projectID, net).Context(ctx).Do()
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    ctx := context.Background()
    clt, err := CreateGCPClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    netserv := CreateNetworksService(clt)

    out, err := CreateVPC(ctx, netserv, "test")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Out: %+v\n", out)
}
```

This is creating a VPC in *legacy* mode instead of *custom* mode. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks/insert) says that `IPv4Range` field is deprecated. In fact, first I tried to elide it completely from `compute.Network` struct. But it gives the same result.

Apparently GCP automatically allocates a default private CIDR (10.240.0.0/16) to the VPC everytime it gets created by this program.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform already found a fix for this issue: [link](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/f2f276ea0b8a98fa782a9321a9d4b55122e27fe5/google/resource_compute_network.go#L83). Apparently `AutoCreateSubnetworks` field is not included in request payload unless explicitely told by `ForceSendFields` property.

In practice, this works:

```
func CreateVPC(ctx context.Context, ns *compute.NetworksService, name string) (*compute.Operation, error) {
    net := &compute.Network{
        Name:                  name,
        AutoCreateSubnetworks: false,
        // make sure AutoCreateSubnetworks field is included in request
        ForceSendFields: []string{"AutoCreateSubnetworks"},
    }
    return ns.Insert(projectID, net).Context(ctx).Do()
}
```

The documentation of `ForceSendFields` says exactly that all empty fields are omitted from request payload. Unfortunately, what it does not say is that if `AutoCreateSubnetworks` is omitted then VPC is created in legacy mode.

> By default, fields with
>     empty values are omitted from API requests. However, any non-pointer,
>     non-interface field appearing in ForceSendFields will be sent to the
>     server regardless of whether the field is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`NetworksService.SwitchToCustomMode`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#NetworksService.SwitchToCustomMode)

> SwitchToCustomMode: Switches the network mode from auto subnet mode to custom subnet mode.

```
func (r *NetworksService) SwitchToCustomMode(project string, network string) *NetworksSwitchToCustomModeCall
```

Comment: Call to that API returns: _main.go:25: googleapi: Error 400: Switching network mode to custom subnet mode is not supported for legacy mode network., badRequest_.